# Template struct in C++ with different data members

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to change what data members are contained in a templated struct based on the parameters? For instance:

```
template<int Asize> struct intxA
{
#if (Asize <= 8)
    int8 num = 0;
#elif (Asize <= 16)
    int16 x = 1;
#endif
};
```

In implementation:

```
intxA<3> struct8;
intxA<11> struct16;
```

I have tried the code above, however, the data member "num" is always present, no matter the value of Asize. Is there a way to do this in C++ without doing it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with partial specialization.

```
template<int Asize, typename = void> struct intxA
{
};
template <int Asize>
struct intxA<Asize, std::enable_if_t<Asize <= 8>>
{
    int8 num = 0;
};
template <int Asize>
struct intxA<Asize, std::enable_if_t<(Asize > 8 && Asize <= 16)>>
{
    int16 x = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

With `std::conditional`:

```
template<int Asize> struct intxA
{
    std::conditional_t<(Asize <= 8), int8, int16> m = Asize <= 8 ? 0 : 1;
};
```

But if you want to give different name, you have to do specialization

Comment: Nitpick: This will use `int16` if `Asize` is greater than 16, which OP's code does not do.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: misread the condition indeed...

Comment: This answer is pretty good too, tho I accepted the specialization one because it is more powerful (since it allows to define something completely different)

Comment: @ZeroZ30o if you specialize the whole struct, you have to duplicate a lot of code regarding equivalent members, methods, etc etc. It's a bit like bringing a ballistic missile to a knife fight. This answer is more suitable for your use case imho.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili well, that was only the beginning that would enable me to start a struct for this concept. Having different functions would actually be essential, in order to split the number into two variables and optimize the code in some cases.

Comment: And even with specialization, you might do it by "block": a common base class for common stuff, and dedicated struct to specialize for specificity.